# How do I append to xlValues in VBA when using the find function?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do something like this:

```
inputSheet.UsedRange.Find(What:=Right("00000" & t.minRowCode, 5), LookIn:=Right("00000" & xlValues, 5))
```

Is this possible or did I do something wrong?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: minRowCode can have values like ("010","10","0010") the excel sheet contains a table that has labels for row codes and column codes. These labels can be ("010","10","0010") . I want to find the row code label even if it might have 2 or 3 zeroes or not in front of it.

Comment: `Lookin` is a constant with the only possibilities being `xlFormulas, xlValues, xlComments or xlCommentsThreaded.`  Look at the Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: @OlteanuRadu - try to rewrite the question, stating 1) what is the input data, 2) what is the expected output data and 3) what you have tried. Points 1 and 2 are currently missing.

Answer (score 0):

> minRowCode can have values like ("010","10","0010") the excel sheet contains a table that has labels for row codes and column codes. These labels can be ("010","10","0010") . I want to find the row code label even if it might have 2 or 3 zeroes or not in front of it. – Olteanu Radu 1 hour ago

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim bCell As Range
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim FoundAt As String
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    '~~> This is your search string
    SearchString = "10"
    
    With ws
        Set aCell = .UsedRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell
            
            '~~> Do a Value comparision rather than adding leading and trailing 0's
            If Val(aCell.Value2) = Val(SearchString) Then
                FoundAt = aCell.Address
            End If
            
            '~~> Find next Entry
            Do
                Set aCell = .UsedRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)
    
                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                    If Val(aCell.Value2) = Val(SearchString) Then
                        FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
        End If
    End With
    
    If FoundAt <> "" Then _
    MsgBox "Found " & SearchString & " in cells " & FoundAt
End Sub
```

[image]

Note: If you are planning to use something like `SearchString = "0010"` then change `What:=SearchString` to `What:=Val(SearchString)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, please:

```
Sub testFindPart()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, C As Range, firstAddress As String
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet

 Set C = sh.UsedRange.Find(What:="10", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)

 firstAddress = C.Address
 If Not C Is Nothing Then
    Do
        Set C = sh.UsedRange.FindNext(C)
        Debug.Print C.Address, C.row
    Loop While C.Address <> firstAddress
 End If
End Sub
```

But, like I said in my comment, it will find also a string as "23451078"...

And, if you need some column headers, you can define the range to be the row in discussion.